# Redirect parent window on child window close

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, dom-events

We have two browser windows:

1. A parent window where the visitor clicks "start chat" -- **W1**
2. A chat window which opens up(popup) when user clicks on "start chat"
   which is from a different domain. -- **W2**

**Requirement**: When the visitor closes the chat window(W2) after the chat, we need the parent window(W1) to redirect to the "thank you" page.

Since W1 and W2 are of different domains, we need to redirect W2 to the same domain as on W1 so that we can redirect W1 from the W2 using JavaScript (same origin policy)

**What I tried**: `onunload` and `onbeforeunload`

**Note**: We do not need to redirect to "thank you" page always( eg: when the chat operator is offline)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems impossible. But I managed to do this with modification in the requirement.

So W1 redirects when the visitor enters the first message(when conversion happens). Not on window close.

**How I did this:**

When the visitor enters first message(in W2), an `iframe` will be created(width and height 0) in W2 which loads a page from the same domain as W1.

And inside iframe I use JavaScript:

`parent.opener.location.href=<link to thank you page>`